# Leverage iptables to drop packets between docker containers

Tags: docker, iptables

I have three containers C1, C2 and C3, forming a cluster, and a DNS instance running. The containers resolve their IPs using the DNS and already can communicate with each other as they expose the needed ports using vanilla docker configuration.

How can I leverage `iptables` from the host to drop packets between say C1 and C2 at any point in time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not clear from your question exactly what your goal is, so here are a few options.

### Disabling ICC

If you run the Docker daemon with `--icc=false`, then containers will *by default* not be able to communicate unless you explicitly link them with `--link`.

If you follow this route, note [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12071) (tl;dr: you must ensure that the `br_netfilter` module is loaded on recent kernels).

### Modifying iptables inside a container

You can use the `nsenter` tool to run `iptables` commands inside a container and add `DROP` rules to the `INPUT` chain of the container.  For example, if you know (a) the PID of container C1 and (b) the ip address of container C2 (both of which you can get with `docker inspect`), you could run:

```
nsenter -t <pid_of_C1> --net iptables -A INPUT -s <ip_of_c2> -j DROP
```

### Modifying iptables on the host

You can modify the `FORWARD` chain on your host to block traffic between particular containers.  For example, to drop packets from C1 to C2:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s <ip_of_c1> -d <ip_of_c2> -j DROP
```

This insert the above rule at position 1 (`-I FORWARD 1`) of the `FORWARD` table.  This is necessary because it must come before the `-i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT` rule that Docker will add to the `FORWARD` chain when `--icc=true`, which is the default.

Comment: I will try your last approach. I always forget that the position of the rule is important.